# aiohttp: Unclosed client session client_session

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I have a `test.py` file and a `AsyncioCurl.py`file.
I already use `session` instead of just `aiohttp.request`
But it also give me this error:

```
Unclosed client session
client_session: <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x000001FAEFEA7DA0>
Unclosed connector
connections: ['[(<aiohttp.client_proto.ResponseHandler object at 0x000001FAF10AC648>, 119890.906)]']
connector: <aiohttp.connector.TCPConnector object at 0x000001FAF0F702B0>
```

**test.py**

```
import asyncio
from AsyncioCurl import AsyncioCurl
async def a():
    payload = {}
    url = "https://awebsiteisthere.com"
    data = await AsyncioCurl().get(url,payload)
    print(data)

task = [
    a()
]

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(task))
```

**AsyncioCurl.py**

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
from Log import Log
from Base import sign
from config import config


class AsyncioCurl:
    def __init__(self):
        self.session = aiohttp.ClientSession(timeout=aiohttp.ClientTimeout(total=4))

    async def get(self,url,param):
        Log.debug("GET: "+url)
        payload = {
            "cookie":config["Token"]["COOKIE"]
        }
        payload = dict(param,**payload)
        payload = sign(payload)
        async with self.session.get(url,params=payload) as r:
            Log.debug(r.status)
            return await r.json()

    async def post(self,url,param):
        async with sem:
            Log.debug("POST: "+url)
            payload = {
                "cookie":config["Token"]["COOKIE"]
            }
            payload = dict(param,**payload)
            payload = sign(payload)
            async with self.session.post(url,data=payload) as r:
                return await r.json()

    async def nspost(self,url,param):
        Log.debug("POST: "+url)
        headers = {
            "Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*",
            "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36",
            "Accept-Language":"zh-CN,zh;q=0.9",
            "accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate",
            "cookie":config["Token"]["COOKIE"]
        }
        async with self.session.post(url,data=param,headers=headers) as r:
            return await r.json()

    async def nsdpost(self,url):
        Log.debug("POST: "+url)
        headers = {
            "Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*",
            "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36",
            "Accept-Language":"zh-CN,zh;q=0.9",
            "accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate",
            "cookie":config["Token"]["COOKIE"]
        }
        async with self.session.post(url,headers=headers) as r:
            return await r.json()
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not an error, just a warning. And you can deal with it by closing the session. Try this:

```
async def a():
    payload = {}
    url = "https://awebsiteisthere.com"
    curl = AsyncioCurl()
    data = await curl.get(url,payload)
    print(data)
    await curl.session.close()  # this
```

Comment: for me `await curl.close() #without session` did the job

Comment: await client.session.close() I need session

Answer (score 0):

I just added the `close()`at the end of your `test.py`script

```html
import asyncio
from AsyncioCurl import AsyncioCurl
async def a():
    payload = {}
    url = "https://awebsiteisthere.com"
    data = await AsyncioCurl().get(url,payload)
    print(data)
    await AsyncioCurl.close() #added this line

task = [
    a()
]

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(task))
```